# Setting Button Content from DatePicker DatePicked event

Tags: c#, datepicker, windows-phone-8.1, silverlight-5.0

I am working on windows phone 8.1 application . I am trying to use DatePickerFlyout but not have proper success. 
I am selecting date and trying to set button content with selected date but it is not setting. When I debug to see if the date is coming or not, and I can see that date is coming properly. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Kindly somebody help me.

1. My Code XML Codes Style

   ```
   <Style TargetType="Button" x:Name="DropDownButton">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="#e6e6e6"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
         <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,10,10"/>
         <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
               <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="65">
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <Image Source="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                               Stretch="None" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                 <TextBlock x:Name="ButtonTextElement" 
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="10,0"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Grid.Column="1" 
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" />
                 <Image Source="{TemplateBinding local:BookAFlight.ImageSource}"
                               Stretch="None" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
               </Grid>
             </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
       </Style>
   ```
2. My XML Code for button

   ```
   <Button Style="{StaticResource DropDownButton}" Tag="/Assets/date-icon.png" x:Name="fromDate"
                 x:Uid="fromDate">
           <Button.Flyout>
             <DatePickerFlyout x:Name="fromDatePicker"/>
           </Button.Flyout>
         </Button>
   ```
3. My C# code

   ```
   public ClassInitializer()
       {
         this.InitializeComponent();
         fromDatePicker.DatePicked += fromDatePicker_DatePicked;
       }

   void fromDatePicker_DatePicked(DatePickerFlyout sender, DatePickedEventArgs args)
       {
         fromDate.Content =  sender.Date;
       }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is needed to set string representation of Date to button's Content.
Like this:

```
void fromDatePicker_DatePicked(DatePickerFlyout sender, DatePickedEventArgs args)
    {
      fromDate.Content =  sender.Date.DateTime.ToString();
    }
```